# How to display a form on mouseover and hide it on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a login p tag,when i mouse over on it i need to display a login form and hide it on mouse out,
How can i do that?

Comment: Show us some code please, we're not psychic ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**Javascript:**

```
function showForm(){
    document.getElementById('loginForm').style.display = "block";
}

function hideForm(){
    document.getElementById('loginForm').style.display = "none";
}
```

**html:**

```
<form>
    <p id="login" onmouseover="showForm();" onmouseout="hideForm();">     
        <span class="label">Login Here</span>       
            <span id="loginForm">        
                <span class="form-elements">
                    <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
                    <span class="form-field"><input type="name" /></span>
                </span>        
                <span class="form-elements">
                    <span class="form-label">Password:</span>
                    <span class="form-field"><input type="password" /></span>
                </span>        
                <span class="form-elements">
                    <span class="submit-btn"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></span>
                </span>    
            </span>          
        </p>
    </form>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/aNWfV/ -- updated link

**Jquery Solution:**

```
$("#login").hover(function() {
    $("#loginForm").css({"display":"block"});
}, function() {
    $("#loginForm").css({"display":"none"});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <p id="login">     
        <span class="label">Login Here</span>       
        <span id="loginForm">        
            <span class="form-elements">
                <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
                <span class="form-field"><input type="name" /></span>
            </span>        
            <span class="form-elements">
                <span class="form-label">Password:</span>
                <span class="form-field"><input type="password" /></span> 
            </span>        
            <span class="form-elements">
                <span class="submit-btn"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></span>
            </span>    
        </span>          
    </p>
</form>
```

See Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/SGUbC/

Comment: One problem: if you mouse out of *Login Here*, the login form disappears. Then how do I login?

Comment: @Swati, I have updated the answer. Kindly mark it correct answer, if you seem it as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What did you try?

> I have a login p tag

For the sake of simplicity (in my favor) let us make it a `div` tag

```
<div class="login">Login</div>
```

And the Form

```
<form id="loginForm"></form>
```

> when i mouse over on it i need to display a login form and hide it on
>   mouse out

```
<div class="login" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide()">Login</div>

function show()
{
    document.getElementById("login").display = "block";
}

function hide()
{
    document.getElementById("login").display = "none";
}
```

This is pretty simple, right? You may want to try something before you ask, from next time.

Hide and show the container div because you don't want the form to hide when the user mouse's out of the parent and mouses-in to the form.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/6dzBn/

Comment: thanks,but i need it to diaplay on a page,can u see this sit,**http://photobucket.com/** inthat on sign in mouse over form appeares on page,how can i do that?

Comment: @swati Photobucket is not accessible from my work location (and from may places). A screenshot/another example would help

Answer (score 0):

```
var formObj = document.getElementById("formName");
formObj .onmouseover = function()
{

this.style.display = "block";
}

formObj.onmouseout = function()
{

this.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: enter document.getElementById("formName") in a var maybe? And I would use css classes

Comment: ...or how about `this.style.display`??