# Show / hide DIV on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a a DIV on image / link hover and i have written following code

```
   $("#NotificationSummary").hover(
      function () {
          $("#dvNotifications").slideDown();
      },
      function () {           

          $("#dvNotifications").slideUp();
      }
    );
```

DIV is showing on hover but when i move to div it hides, How can i stop div from hiding while mouse is over it

please view the demo http://jsfiddle.net/3hqrW/15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**reedit** based on comment] jsfiddle revised, removed css-only solution. The trick is to monitor the hover state of the sliding element and use a timeout to allow the user to move over the slided element (see also comments in the updated jsfiddle).

jsfiddle derived from OPs jsfiddle [@here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9v5A/)

The hover function using your #ids:

```
function hover(e){
 e = e || event;
 var el = e.target || e.srcElement
    ,showel = $('#dvNotifications')
 ;
 if (!/NotificationSummary/i.test(el.id)) {
  showel .attr('data-ishovered',/over/i.test(e.type));
 } else {
  showel .attr('data-ishovered',false)
 }

 if (/true/i.test(showel .attr('data-ishovered'))){return true;}

 if (/over$/i.test(e.type) && /NotificationSummary/i.test(el.id)){
    showel .slideDown();
 } else {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (/false/i.test(showel .attr('data-ishovered'))) {
            showel .slideUp();
            showel .attr('data-ishovered',false);
        }
      }
    ,200);
 }
```

}

Comment: it is not working on IE, just flickers. BTW I dont like writing thing browser specific

Comment: Yeah, IE (version 10 may work though, or using Google Chrome Frame (https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/)).

Comment: @KooiInc: Lower div remains open forever if you never point your pointer to the lower div. See in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/3hqrW/54/

Comment: @Ahsan: yep, it was too simple. Revised it, should work now (IE too).

Comment: @KooiInc can you please update this http://jsfiddle.net/3hqrW/15/ by using your technique.

Comment: @KooiInc same result... http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/3hqrW/91/ when you hover, it will show the div, don't move mouse pointer over the div which is visible on hover. Just move you point upwards.. You can see then the div is visible..

Comment: @Tanveer: I think it's too complicated to implement. Because `#dvNotifications` is not inside the `<a>`.

Comment: @Ahsan: nothing is too complicated. I have adapted your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FNEmP/ en tested it in 3 browsers. Worked here.

Comment: @Koolinc: Now it is fine.. Good Job.. Kindly Add your fiddle in your answer. So Tanveer can mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tanveer, Koolinc has updated fiddle and it is working fine as you have required.

Comment: Thanks @KooiInc and ahsan , its a great solution working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Tanveer kindly see this **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/3hqrW/

The div you want to display on hover should be inside the main div on which you want to hover, and main div should have css attributes: `display:block`

**Another Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/SGUbC/

Comment: How did you know his html structure ?

Comment: @Blaster I didn't know his HTML structure, but I am suggesting him this structure, because i have already suggested this in following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146281/how-to-display-a-form-on-mouseover-and-hide-it-on-mouseout/7146486

Comment: @AhsanRathod good answer but i am implementing functionality like facebook notifications, image is in header file and div to be shown is in page. I have positioned the div by css and now just want to show /hide div. I am trying your technique in the meanwhile if you have some other idea then please suggest

Comment: @Tanveer: See my another Demo hope it will helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/EqMFJ/

Comment: @AhsanRathod please view http://jsfiddle.net/3hqrW/15/ , I just want that if i move to lower div it should not hide ,should hide only if pointer go away from both divs

Answer (score -1):

```
  $("#NotificationSummary").mouseenter(function() {
       $("#dvNotifications").fadeIn();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
      $("#dvNotifications").fadeOut();
  });
```

Comment: What you want to achieve by doing this?